# old .aspx URL redirect to new WordPress URL

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A client of mine had me redesign his old asp.net website and I have developed it using WordPress. Same domain name. It is finished and live.

During this transition, I had to re-create nearly 250 landing pages and name them using the same url structure that they were named previously, primarily for SEO purposes and the fact that these pages and links are numerous places on the web.

Although, I suspected this would require a RewriteRule in the .htaccess file, this hasn't been a seamless transition for us at all.

I need to have to redirect: 
http://website.com/pages/about-us.aspx to http://website.com/pages/about-us/

Currently, my .htaccess file includes the following:

```
AddHandler php-stable .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.aspx -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is having no affect and I still get a 404 error when going to these .aspx pages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.aspx -f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).aspx$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This was actually the first code I entered that didn't work. So unfortunately this isn't what I need. Is there perhaps a certain code I might be missing that needs to be included on the site's .htaccess file or in the header? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried placing above the other rewrite rules?

Comment: Thank you!!!! That did it.  I appreciate it SO much! just saved me hours of work. I suppose this is where my lack of programming knowledge comes into play. This was a detail I did not find in any of my searches.  Many, many thanks!